# MySQL query for "self-tabled" rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got some table

```
CREATE TABLE receptions (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    personID int(11),
    manager varchar(255),
    timestamp datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    flag tinyint(1),
);
```

EXAMPLE: I have some data
[image: data]

And want to get rows `WHERE flag = 1` like

`id | personID | "last_manager" | "last_timestamp" | "prev_manager" | "prev_timestamp"`

`3  |   1      |     manager2  | 01.11.2017 11:00:23 | manager1    | 01.11.2017 10:00:00`

`6  |   2      |     manager3  | 01.11.2017 14:00:00 | manager3    | 01.11.2017 13:00:23`

... and so on. Sorry for formatting.

Is it possible to do using single query to get data in such format ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM temp WHERE flag = 1 lol

Comment: manager depends on personID?

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko no, it is different objects

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer. Can you share sample data and expected output?

Comment: How many managers can a person have? What is the difference between `last_manager` and `prev_manager`? Is there a `current_manager` or is that the same as `last_manager`?

Comment: For each ID in reception, there could be multiple managers and you want to see the most recent and the previous?  Some sample data and expected output as @Honeybadger indicated would be very useful.

Comment: Please refer to edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I haven't tried this out - please provide sample data and expected results, ideally as a SQLFiddle. But the essence is a self join, with MAX to find the latest and latest-but-one rows.

```
    select last.id, 
last.personID,
last.manager as last_manager,
max(last.timestamp) as "last_timestamp",
previous.manager as "prev_manager",
max(previous.timestamp) as "prev_timestamp"
from   receptions last
inner join receptions previous on previous.personid = last.personid
where last.timestamp > previous.timestamp
and last.flag = 1
group by last.id, 
last.personID
```

[Here'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72a89/2)s a SQLFiddle.

Comment: I think the query above should achieve that.

Comment: error "Unknown column 'last.personID' in 'field list'"

Comment: thanks a lot but it doesn't work on both my servers (linux and windows) using dbForge and Heidisql. I'm using MariaDB 10.1

Comment: How does it "not work"? Does it not return the data you expect, does it show error messages?

Comment: error "Unknown column 'last.personID' in 'field list'"

Comment: sorry got some code mistake. Now everything works. Thanks a lot!